# Express each of these as a combination of $p$ and $q$.

Tags: logic

The given question is:

Let $p$ be the proposition “I will do every exercise in this book” and q be the proposition “I will get an “A” in this course.” Express each of these as a combination of $p$ and $q$.

a) I will get an “A” in this course only if I do every exercise in this book.

This is of form $q$ only if $p$

I know the answer is clearly $p\to q$.

But I have the statement: The implication $p\to q$ is the proposition that is false when $p$ is true and $q$ is false, and true otherwise.

If $p$ is true and $q$ is false, the statement is "I will not get an “A” in this course only if I do every exercise in this book", which is false as it contradicts our given statement.

for $p$ and $q$ both true, it gives the given statement. So true.

If both $p$ and $q$ are false, we get "I will not get an “A” in this course only if I will not  do every exercise in this book", which is same as saying "If I will not do every exercise in this book then i will not get “A” in this course"  this sounds true as compare to our given statement.

But what about this statement, when $p$ is false and $q$ is true, which says "I will get an “A” in this course only if I will not  do every exercise in this book", how this statement will be true, I am not getting?

For me this sounds opposite to the previous case, when $p$ and $q$ both are false. Then how both can be true. Where I am wrong, please explain..

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

> This is of form 
> only if
>
> I know the answer is clearly  →

Really?

Then what would be your rendition of   if  ??

Can e.g. 'Jack will win the race only if he trains hard' really be rendered by 'Jack trains hard → he will win the race' ???

Take a look at the chapter on conditionals in any decent intro logic texts ... e.g. Ch. 18 of https://www.logicmatters.net/resources/pdfs/IFL2_LM.pdf

Comment: so the answer is $q \to p$. But $q \to p$ is true when $q$ is false and $p$ is true. How can  I show that?

Answer (score 0):

Let's think about the falsity conditions of the natural language sentence.

> I will get an A in the course only if I do every exercise in the book.

This sentence is false if and only if you can get an A in the course (q) without doing every exercise in the book (p). So, the original sentence is equivalent to $\lnot(q \land \lnot p)$, which is equivalent to $q \to p$.

The related sentence below is false exactly when *you do every exercise in the book (p), but fail to get an A (q).*

> I will get an A in the course if I do every exercise in the book.

The original sentence is equivalent to $\lnot(p \land \lnot q)$, which is equivalent to $p \to q$.

---

As an addendum, I think it would help to rearrange the sentence so that the conditional clause is first when translating a sentence into logical form. Even if the conditional clause is headed by something weird like an `only if`.

> I will get an A in the course only if I do every exercise in the book.

Is equivalent to

> Only if I do every exercise in the book, I will get an A in the course.

This makes the paraphrase into an `if` easier to see and convince yourself of.

> If I get an A in the course, then I did every exercise in the book

Comment: So, you mean, the answer should be $q \to p$?

Comment: Yes, `only if` is the converse, in a sense, of `if`, but the condition is the clause that appears immediately after the `only if`. So you need to flip the clauses around twice in order to get it into a more familiar form. Thinking about when a sentence is false and paraphrasing it so that it is easier to convert into symbolic form are both good strategies for this kind of exercise.

Comment: But if it is $q \to p$, then this must be true when $q$ is false and $p$ is true. Can you tell me the resulting statement when $q$ is false and $p$ is true?

Comment: Please reply, something wrong with my question?

Comment: $q \rightarrow p$ is true *unless* $q$ is true and $p$ is false. There's only one conclusion we can potentially draw from the original statements: you can't pass without doing the homework, so if you passed, you must have done the homework. $q \rightarrow p$, as everyone else has said.

Comment: As an exercise, I'd recommend making truth tables for `If P, Q`, `Q if P`, `Only if P, Q`, and `Q only if P`. Some of them will have the same truth tables. I think the answer will become clear after doing this.